# Where is the exe file from MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#

I just made a project and it runs in MonoDevelop, but I would like to run it myself from commandline so I know I can just give the exe file onwards and I can't find the exe file for it. So is there some special place I should look for it?

Comment: "`so I know I can just give the exe file onwards`" -- you do know that you also need to make sure the right .Net Framework is installed, right? Sometimes you can just hand out an exe, but more often you need to do that check as well.

Comment: For the future, building locations etc. are identical for Visual Studio and MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a better link that than these two -

http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Copying-files-to-output-directory-in-MonoDevelop-td1514760.html

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodevelop-list/2009-January/008833.html

But it seems to suggest the output can be configured by you.  You can see it in the .csproj file.  The default appears to be `../ProjectFolder/Bin/Release/` or `../ProjectFolder/Bin/Debug/`